# Why is Altium not copying polygons anymore in mutli-channel mode & rooms?

Tags: pcb, altium

I'm doing a somehow complex hierarchial design.

I got a here 4 seperate rooms, that are overlapping. All works just fine. I even managed to copy the one on the right side with the large cyan colored power plane to all other channels.

The issue is with the other room. The cyan colored power plane (on the bottom over C36, CC40, C25, C33) on Layer 3 (PWR) won't copy to the adjacent one, but all other components and routings work fine (from Layer 1 & 4 as far as I can see). Anyone knows, why this is happening? The software is apparently capable of this, it's just not executing it correctly for me

[image]

Now I added a new polygons to Layer 3 to the working room (PLL) and it's not getting copied as before, so my guess is that I ruined messed up some preferences:
[image: preference]

Here's also how I use the copy room option each time (I don't think anything changed to previous copy, when it worked):
[image]

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).